# multiple google plus buttons (one in rails view, one in a partial that the rails view has a link to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-plus-one

I'm using the G+ button on a page.  This is all great, but when I load a modal box that has a partial page on top of this page, the G+ button on the modal box does not show up.

Pretty sure this is because the G+ on the modal box is using the same id as the page (___plusone_0).  Normally this # increments (__plusone_1, ___plusone_2, etc) but for some reason the one in the partial doesn't know about the other buttons.  How can I fix this?